# Let $P_A(x)$ denote the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A$. Let $P_A(x)-P_{A^{-1}}(x) = c$......(1), where $c$ is a constant.

Tags: matrices, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

Let $P_A(x)$ denote the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A_{n×n} , n \geq 2$.  Let $P_A(x)-P_{A^{-1}}(x) = c$......(1), where $c$ is a constant. Then which type of matrix satisfy (1)

My Attempt:

I saw a matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 \\
4 & 3 
\end{pmatrix}
$$ which gives $P_A(x)-P_{A^{-1}}(x) = 0$.

I see here that $Det(A) = Det(A^{-1}) = 1$ and $Trace(A) = Trace (A^{-1})$ but I have no idea in general. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you precise what $P_{A^{-1}}$ is as you’re not using the unknown $x$ as for $P_A(x)$?

Comment: I edited. Thanks for point out a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Since $P_M(x)=\det(xI-M)$ for any matrix $M$, we have the relation
\begin{align*}
P_A(x)
&=\det(xI-A)\\
&=\det(A)\det(xA^{-1}-I)\\
&=\det(A)(-x)^n\det\left(\frac1xI-A^{-1}\right)\\
&=\det(A)(-x)^nP_{A^{-1}}(1/x).
\end{align*}
In other words,
$$P_{A^{-1}}(x)=(-1)^n\frac{x^nP_A(1/x)}{\det(A)}.$$
The polynomial in the numerator represents "reversing" the polynomial $P_A$, by swapping its $x^0$ and $x^n$ coefficients, $x^1$ and $x^{n-1}$ coefficients, etc. Also, $(-1)^n\det A=P_A(0)$. Write $P(x)=P_A(x)$ for simplicity. We then suppose $P_A(x)-P_{A^{-1}}(x)=c$ for some constant $c$. This gives the identity
$$\tag{1}P(x)-c=\frac{x^nP(1/x)}{P(0)}.$$
Since this also implies
$$P(1/x)=c+\frac{x^{-n}P(x)}{P(0)},$$
we get
$$P(x)=c+\frac{x^n}{P(0)}\left(\frac{x^{-n}P(x)}{P(0)}+c\right)=c\left(\frac{x^n}{P(0)}+1\right)+\frac{P(x)}{P(0)^2}.$$
If $P(0)=\pm 1$, then we also require $c=0$; otherwise,
$$P(x)=\frac{c\left(\frac{x^n}{P(0)}+1\right)}{1-\frac1{P(0)^2}}.$$
We may substitute in $x=0$ to solve for $c$ and get $c=P(0)-1/P(0)$, and so
$$P(x)=x^n+P(0),$$
which does satisfy $(1)$. In the case where $P(0)=\pm 1$ and $c=0$, any polynomial
$$x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$$
with $a_0=\pm 1$ and $a_j=a_0a_{n-j}$ will satisfy $(1)$.

Characterizing the matrices with these characteristic polynomials will be a lot trickier, since a characteristic polynomial carries much less information than a matrix itself. You could write out the roots of such a polynomial and find all the possible Jordan normal forms, if you want, but there won't be a simple answer like "nilpotent" or "skew-symmetric."